# Implementing a butterworth bandfilter using scipy on a raspberry pi

Tags: python, filter, scipy, signals, butterworth

I have code that uses scipy.signal.butter. It works fine on my windows computer but when I run it on my raspberry pi 4 I get this error

```
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Python/Data_analysis_bandfitting.py", line 64, in analysis

    sos = signal.butter(10, high, 'hp', fs=Fs, output='sos')


TypeError: butter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fs'
```

I'm not sure why this would work on windows but not linux. I have the latest libraries installed on both my computer and the raspberry pi.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I doubt that you have the latest version installed on the Pi.  Please run `pip list` and confirm which version you have.

Comment: You can also check the version of scipy that you are using by running the Python code  `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: You're right ```pip list``` returned scipy version 1.1.0 while ```pip3 list``` returned version 1.4.1. I ran ```import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)``` and saw that spyder was using version 1.1.0. Thank you both for your help.